# Does a discriminant condition on $f(x,y)$ imply that $f$ is weighted homogeneous?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, toric-varieties, discriminant

[This is an updated version of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522399/.]

Let $f = \sum_{i=0}^n f_iy^i \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be a polynomial (where $f_i \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $f_0,f_n \ne 0$), and let $\operatorname{Disc}_y(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ be the discriminant of $f$ with respect to $y$ (i.e., for every $a \in \mathbb{C}$, $\operatorname{Disc}_y(a)$ is the discriminant of $f(a,y)$). I got the impression that $f$ is weighted homogeneous (with possibly negative weights) if and only if the following three conditions hold:

1. $f_0$ is a (non-zero) monomial in $x$
2. $f_n$ is a (non-zero) monomial in $x$
3. $\operatorname{Disc}_y$ is a non-zero monomial in $x$

The direction "$\Rightarrow$" should not be too hard to prove: 1 and 2 are clear, and I think that 3 follows from the formula expressing the discriminant in terms of the coefficients of a polynomial. My question is: Is "$\Leftarrow$" also (known to be) true?

Some thoughts/remarks:

- If one thinks of $f$ as defining a variety $V \subset \mathbb{C}^\times \times \mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{C}$, then 1 and 2 say that $V \subset \mathbb{C}^\times \times \mathbb{C}^\times$, and 3 says that the projection to the first coordinate is unramified.
- Consider $g := y \cdot \partial f/\partial y$. It is not hard to verify that 1, 2 and 3 together are equivalent to: the subvarieties of $\mathbb{C}^\times \times \mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f$ and $g$ have empty intersection. Applying a version of Bezout's Theorem for subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{C}$ thus yields a lot of intersections above $0$ and $\infty$. I got the impression that one might be able to prove the claim in this way, namely by bounding intersection multiplicities in those fibers using the basic techniques from Fulton's "Algebraic Curves". (In this way, I was able to prove the claim in a number of particular cases.)